# Spring Test MockMvc perform request on external URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, spring-test

I'm trying to perform a POST request on URL outside the current context, and it looks like Spring cannot understand it.

Test code:

```
        String content = mvc
            .perform(post("http://some-external-url.com:8080/somepath)
                    .header("Authorization", authorization)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                    .param("username", username)
                    .param("password", password)
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Works like a charm on current context.  But remote service cannot be reached at all. It seems like "http://some-external-url.com:8080" part is ignored.

Mock creation code:

```
mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
```

Is there any way to make it work? Because using standard Java HttpUrlConnection class is a huge pain.

Comment: Why are you expecting that MockMvc would work on external URLs?

Comment: Why not? It's just a testing tool, right?. To test my controller properly at first I should get some information from external web-service. I don't think it's very rare case.

Comment: It's a testing tool that very specifically emulates a small, isolated section of the Servlet stack. There's no HTTP client involved anywhere, and only part of an HTTP server. You might as well say that since Selenium is a testing tool, it should modify database schema.

Comment: Just a friendly note that if you find one of the answers to your question acceptable, feel free to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you want to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. There is no way to make the Spring MVC Test Framework work with external servers (or any actual server for that matter).

As stated in the [Spring Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework),

> The Spring MVC Test framework provides first class support for testing
>   Spring MVC code using a fluent API that can be used with JUnit,
>   TestNG, or any other testing framework. It’s built on the Servlet API
>   mock objects from the spring-test module and hence does not use a
>   running Servlet container.

The last sentence spells it out: Spring MVC Test does **not** use a running Servlet container. In fact, it cannot be used with a running Servlet container or any kind of actual server (local or remote).

As an alternative, if you *must* test against an external server, you could then consider using [REST Assured](http://rest-assured.io/) instead of Spring MVC Test for those special cases.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation.

Comment: FYI: I added a note about REST Assured.

Comment: For my own reference: This means that MockMVC does not put an HTTPRequest on the network, is just an in-JVM test

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new RestTemplate().getForObject("http://some-external-url.com:8080/somepath", String.class)`